# Check multiple variables to verify session access to page

Tags: php, sql, session, authentication

For most of my site I can happily just verify the user id exists to show restricted content to registered users. But I want to develop an admin interface for easier management and only allow access to a certain set of pages only if two (or more) conditions are met.

The two conditions I have in mind are the the User ID (every registered user will have one) but then i'd like to verify the role of that user and have the option of pulling a value from the user_role column of my table. There are currently three possibilities; admin, editor and reader.

I can't quite figure out how to get the query to trigger the check, my existing session code is;

```
// Here we check to see whether the user is logged in or not 
    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    { 
        // If they are not, redirect them to the login page. 
        header("Location: login.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
    }
```

How could I add an additional `$_SESSION` variable to check the role of a user?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You can add the user_role in your session when you will login someone to your admin interface. Or just put the user_id in session and query your database to check the user_role. Is that your question?

Comment: Yes - when a user with the admin role logs in at domain.com/admin/ the table is checked and they are logged in. If they have a role like editor or reader they are redirected to domain.com/login/ as they do not have admin permissions.

Comment: Try this :

`if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    { 
        // If they are not, redirect them to the login page. 
        header("Location: login.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
    } else { /*query to check the user role*/ }`

Comment: @RaphaëlGonçalves It is the query I'm having most difficulty with. I'm familiar with if statements.

Comment: You'll need to share your table structure

Comment: Table structure for `users` is - `id, username, password, salt, email, created, user_role`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this maybe (This is assuming that on login and register you set a $_SESSION variable containing their user id or some other identifier):

```
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    { 
        // If they are not, redirect them to the login page. 
        header("Location: login.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
} else 
    {
        include_once("databaseConnection.php");
        $checkAdmin = "SELECT user_role FROM users WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."';";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $checkAdmin);
        $user_role = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($user_role == "reader") 
            {
                // User is only a reader, redirecting them to the home page
                header("Location: /");  
                die("You're only a reader and you're not allowed here, redirecting you to the home page!");
        } elseif ($user_role == "editor")
            {
                // User is only an editor, redirecting them to the home page
                header("Location: /");
                die("You're only an editor and you're not allowed here, redirecting you to the home page!");        
        } elseif ($user_role == "editor")
            {
                // User is an admin, allowing them through
        } else
            {
            //Error identifying user's role
            header("Location: /");
            die("Some kind of error occured, show this to the site owner: (User role identification error)");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't seem to be working though - I think something with my db connection file (common.php) may be conflicting - pastebin: http://pastebin.com/GizQLj76

Comment: Create a new database connection file and use this function: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

Comment: Thanks - still can't get it it to login and redirect properly - edited code http://pastebin.com/9QRnmk82

Answer (score 0):

The approach I'd recommend would also take into consideration the actual number of such privileged users. If you have a lot of such users, consider that you'd add additional load on the server checking the database for each user at each page load, case in which I'd go with a session stored variable that grants access to certain pages and functionalities. The session is actually stored on the server, so the user couldn't just edit it like he would a cookie, so this should provide enough security.

The solution also should consider how scalable and flexible you want it to be. If you find just a few restricted rights, you could just very well enable or disable bits in a integer and store it in the session var. Then just check the right with a simple mask. If, on the other hand, you find more than just a few rights, you could go with a string of user rights. For example: "ab" should give a user rights to add a new post (a) and edit posts of other users (b). This approach should provide more scalability. I used this method on an actual php implementation for a similar case of back-end administration.

If you would want something more responsive in terms of immediate-effect that would not require the user to login again, I'd go with something more close to MQTT as this is very scalable and easily managed. For this you can use the open-source Paho client and instantiate each login so you can async send data between them. This functionality can also be achieved using some JavaScript libraries, but I'm a bit out-dated there as I didn't give those a look since a few years back.